# Next Server Actions with Axios

Tags: axios, next.js14

How can I leverage Next.js 14 Server Actions with Axios for server-side communication?

Are there specific methods or best practices for integrating Axios with Next.js 14 Server Actions to achieve seamless server-side functionality?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Server Actions directly with server-side components or as an event handler on client-side like "onClick".

You don't need to use Axios or fetch data unless you want to fetch data on a client component directly when rendering with `useEffect`.

In this case, you can use `/app/api/your-api-name/route.js` to write your API endpoint.